# Extract bit from a HEX string

Tags: python, hex

This is my code

```
data[12] = '\x18'
c = 4
d = c & data[12]
print d
```

Output/Error

```
Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Please help to solve this problem.

I need to extract which bit is high out of 8 bits.

Like this `'\x18'` has two bits high I want to have those location.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = c & ord(data[12])
```

You can't do binary arithmetics on strings, so convert this string to a number.

In your case, `\xSOMETHING` represents a single (possibly non-printable) character which has a corresponding position in the ASCII set. Retrieve it with `ord`, which returns a number (`24` in your case).

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x18'` That's what

Comment: @Uzzee, yeah, it'll be 24, you're right. Corrected it :)

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, 
I need to check which bits are high in '/x18'

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, 
I need to check which bits are high in '/x18'
'\x18' that is what I am receiving from Zigbee (API mode packet)
I want to ANDing it with 3rd, 4th and 5th bit.
I want to see whether Zigbee has those bits high or low 
So by converting it in '24' is not helping me.

Comment: That's right.
But the next thing, I have to deal with such string is:
Suppose zigbee is sending two byte HEX data (as part of API packet)

in that 26 byte long packet, I successfully extract required two bytes which is the analog value I need.

value is 02 84
Now the actual value is (284)hex = (644)decimal

How can I convert '\x02' '\x84' into 644 ?

Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: Got the Answer:
c = ord(data[23])
c = c*256
b = ord(data[24])
e = c + b

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a single character to its integer equivalent with `ord`.

```
d = c & ord(data[12])
```

If you have more than a single character (byte) to convert, use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>H', '\x02\x84')[0]
644
```

This is particularly useful if you're decoding a number of bytes that make up a structure, as it seems from your comments. You can decode the entire packet at one shot.

Comment: @Uzzee it wasn't when I wrote it, in fact the existing answer was totally incorrect but was edited as I was typing up mine.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment then?

Comment: @Uzzee if an answer is close and I think it can be fixed, I leave a comment - I've done this many times in the past. In this case it wasn't clear that the other answerer understood the problem, so the appropriate response was to leave my own alternative answer. My crystal ball isn't always 100%, which explains why I'm here instead of sipping a drink on a faraway beach after winning the lottery.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, I need to check which bits are high in '/x18' '\x18' that is what I am receiving from Zigbee (API mode packet) I want to ANDing it with 3rd, 4th and 5th bit. I want to see whether Zigbee has those bits high or low So by converting it in '24' is not helping me

Comment: @JPatel why is that not helping you? 24 is a value with bits 3 and 4 set, but not bit 5. If you need to check each individual bit, you need to `and` with 3 separate values.

Comment: That's right. But the next thing, I have to deal with such string is: Suppose zigbee is sending two byte HEX data (as part of API packet) in that 26 byte long packet, I successfully extract required two bytes which is the analog value I need. value is 02 84 Now the actual value is (284)hex = (644)decimal How can I convert '\x02' '\x84' into 644 ? Thank you very much for all your help – J Patel 1 hour ago

Comment: @JPatel I wonder why StackOverflow didn't inform me of your reply? Hopefully my update is useful even though it's late.